# Rerender doesn't work on CommandButton

Tags: rerender, form

I have a problem with `rerender=""`, here is the code :

```
    <apex:form id ="form_id">
    ..
    ..
    ..
    <apex:repeat value="{!map_condidat_cv}" var="key" >
    <tr>
     <td><apex:outputField value="{!map_condidat_cv[key].Nom__c}"/></td>
     <td><apex:outputField value="{!map_condidat_cv[key].Email__c}"/></td>
     <td><apex:outputField value="{!map_condidat_cv[key].Adresse__c}"/></td>
     <td><apex:outputField value="{!map_condidat_cv[key].Statut__c}" id="statusA"/></td>
    <td><apex:outputField value="{!map_condidat_cv[key].Motif_de_Refus__c}" id="MobileR"/></td>
    <td><apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Voir le CV" action="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!key.id}" /></td>

// here is the problem 
    ***<td><apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Le status suivant" action="{!StatusSuivant}" rerender="form_id">
    <apex:param name="condidatID" value="{!map_condidat_cv[key].id}" assignTo="{!condidatID}"/> 
     </apex:commandButton> 
    </td>***


    <td>
    <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" action="{!valider}" value="Valider" rerender="form_id">      
    <apex:param name="condidatID" value="{!map_condidat_cv[key].id}" assignTo="{!condidatID}"/>     
     </apex:commandButton> 
    </td>
```

when i click on the button `Le status suivant`, it does not rerender the form,  knowing that when i click on the second button `Valider` it works and it renders the form correctly. any ideas ?

Comment: Hi. Do your two actions return the same thing? Void or PageReference?

Comment: they return void both methods

Comment: are you masking errors by not including `apex:pageMessages` ?  are you sure that the controller method `statusSuivant` is not entered?  Also, `voir le CV` should be using `URLFOR`

Comment: @crop1645 , i did not understand what do you mean by masking errors ?

Comment: "masking errors" - if apex:pageMessages is missing from the VF page, any error caught by the controller will NEVER appear on the VF page (i.e. "masked" == "hidden" )